# Can Windows 10 of KVM's guest OS use hot plugging (hot swapping) of USB devices?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Can Windows 10 of KVM's guest OS use hot plugging (hot swapping) of USB devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure this in `virt-manager` (KVM). Here's how:

0. Open KVM (if it's not already open)
1. Select the VM you wish to modify
2. Choose "Add Hardware" from the lower-left corner:
   [image: Virtual Manager Settings]
3. Select "USB Host Device", then choose the USB device you wish to pass-through to the VM:
   [image: Add USB Host Device]
4. Save your changes

Now, when that USB device is plugged in (or removed) while the virtual machine is running, the VM will have direct access to the hardware.

Comment: matigo.
The solution you offered solved my problem.
Thank you very much.
Also, thank you.